# Is there any way of to know how many seconds elapsed since the ajax call init?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm developing an ajax application using jQuery.
And my question is the next one.
Is there any way of to know how many seconds elapsed since the ajax call init?

I just want to change the loader message to "Still working..." when the ajax call is taking more than 10 seconds.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376809/implementing-this-is-taking-too-long-message-with-jquery

Comment: great! thanks! i didn't find it when was searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(window).ajaxInit(function() {
    clearTimeout($.ns.tooLongTimer);
    $.ns.tooLongTimer = setTimeout(function() {
         $("#foo").text("TOO LONG");
    }, 10000);
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
    clearTimeout($.ns.tooLongTimer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

call the timer before the ajax call with setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function(){},10000);
```